# Calling an JS function on change with a JS variable as a parameter

Tags: javascript, html

Function1 calls showCyclists() by calling, at the end of function1,  using a parameter, showCyclists(country.id). This launches the showCylists function.

```
    function showCyclists(countryID){  //creates a table with athlete of country
        function cyclistOrder() { //checks on change select box and appends to sort
            sql="SELECT name, ISO_id, height, weight, gender FROM `Cyclist`"; //get info from cyclist db

            select = document.getElementById("selectCycle")

            if(select.value == "height"){
                sql += " ORDER BY height ";
            }

            return sql;
        }
//continue with showCyclists()
```

I need to find a way to execute this function with the same parameter (country id) on change of a select box.

Obviously I can't do `<select id="selectCycle" class="select-cycle" onchange="showCyclists()">` because I'd be calling my function with no parameter.

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `onchange="showCyclists(value)"`

Comment: That doesnt work. it calls the function with as a parameter value, when it should be a country ID that is acquired in function1.

Comment: i don't see `function1`, but if it wraps the other, you can just use closure to reach the parameter...

Comment: They arent nested functions.

Comment: pass the value or use bind() to set this or an argument from the caller

Answer (score 1):

modify the `onchange="showCyclists()` to `onchange="showCyclists(this)` then you have access the parameter you need as `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` inside the function.  You will need to put the right countryID in the value declaration of each select option.

Comment: missing a `.target`?

Comment: What is e meant to be?

Comment: `e` was a typo for `this`